# PyQGIS standalone - GDAL_DATA failure to retrieve gcs.csv using the QgsCoordinateReferencesSystem

Tags: pyqgis

I'm writing a standalone PyQGIS application. In order to set the project CRS, I'm using the `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` class. I tried all the possible methods to assign the crs I want (which is EPSG:32632, but I also tried with the standard EPSG:4326), and none is working (failure verified with `isValid` method). When I use `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.createFromUserInput('EPSG:32632)`, I get the following error:

> ERROR 4: ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv. Try
> setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory
> containing EPSG csv files.

I therefore deduced that this could be the problem preventing every method I tried from working. However, the GDAL_DATA path is set in my batch file running the script by calling the `o4w_env.bat`, and it is correctly set to the default for OSGeo4W64 installation, which is `C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal`.

The file `gcs.csv` is correctly located in the pointed directory. Within my script, I repeatedly verify the `GDAL_DATA` variable, as well as `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH`, `GEOTIFF_CSV` and `PROJ_LIB`: they're all set to the default values for OSGeo4W64 installation, and are never changed within the script.

Since all the paths are correct, and the `gcs.csv` is actually located in the pointed directory, I can't really get where the issue might be rising from.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured out it was an enviroment setting problem. However it was not related to the GDAL_DATA path, but to QGIS_PREFIX_PATH (**NOTE:** settings are referred to standard OSGeo4W64 installation on Windows 10).

I already had the following:

```
os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX'] = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/share/gdal'
```

Adding the following line solved the issue:

```
os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH'] = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis'
```